# How to synchronize pausing and unpausing game using Photon Unity Networking (PUN)

Tags: unity, synchronization, photon

I need some help figuring out how to synch pausing and unpausing the game to other players.

I have a UI button where players can pause using the code I have posted below. Pausing works fine with all the players, however unpausing the game gives me a problem.  Only the player who pressed that unpause button successfully unfreezes while other players remain in the paused state.

```
[PunRPC]
void SetPause(float time) {
    Time.timeScale = time;
}

// this goes to UI button
public void PauseTime(float time) {
    PV.RPC("SetPause", RpcTarget.All, time);
}
```